# Set emmision color unity same with albedo image from url

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

I have script like this to fetch image online and assign it to the albedo when the image was loaded. Now my project was like Pic 2 , the photo can assigned to the albedo of my material.  Can anyone help me to add some code to make the image can be assigned to albedo and emission color like pic 1 after image downloaded?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

public class SphereImageLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material sphereMaterial;
    public string imageUrl ;

     void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DownloadAndApplyTextureCoroutine(imageUrl));
    }

    IEnumerator DownloadAndApplyTextureCoroutine(string url)
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError || www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error downloading texture: " + www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Texture2D texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);

            // Set the downloaded texture as the albedo
            if (sphereMaterial != null)
            {
                sphereMaterial.mainTexture = texture;

                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I only can change  the emmision color by add some brightness from code, but cant assign from downloaded image.